Prisma ORM: Many to many on the same model, multi directional, inferring parent model?
I have a simple concept I'm struggling to understand regarding many-to-many relationships in Prisma. I have a model, an "Artist" and I want to have a relatedArtists array to show similar artists. Similar artists are bi-directional, meaning there is no concept of one direction taking precedent over another.
model Artist {
    id        String   @id @default(uuid())
    createdAt DateTime @default(now())
    updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt

    slug String @unique

    relatedArtists RelatedArtist[] @relation("relatedArtist")
    artists        RelatedArtist[] @relation("artists")
}

I am familiar with the many to many and relations attribute to set up and have both models populate. I have a RelatedArtist model join that houses both an artist and a related artist on it. It works fine and I’m able to join the records using this model:
model RelatedArtist {
    relatedArtistId String
    relatedArtist   Artist @relation("relatedArtist", fields: [relatedArtistId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade, onUpdate: Cascade)

    artistId String
    artist   Artist @relation("artists", fields: [artistId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade, onUpdate: Cascade)

    @@id([artistId, relatedArtistId])
}

What I’m confused with or wondering is this:
Depending on how I connect the model, the children are different when I retrieve the record. for example, if I connect artist A to artist B, and in artist A want to pull the related model for B, I use “artist.relatedArtists” to pull the data.
However, in model B, I have a different field name so i use “artist.artists” to pull artist A.
relatedArtists: {
            include: {
              artist: true,
              relatedArtist: true,
            },
          },

What I'm doing now is basically returning an object that is an array of both include fields:
relatedArtists: [...artist.relatedArtists, ...artist.artists].filter(
          (n) => n,
        ),

Is there a more clever or better way to do this? What I'd like to do is quite simple; just have the same "include" field returned on both models so I don't have to do this messy back and forth juggling between which "side" the relation was originally created on.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking. That's the canned feedback that I can provide about this question. But I wanted to add that specifically you should add a better repro of a concrete example and you might get a response from a Prisma expert. Often times when you do this, you will end up rubber ducking your own answer (which you can provide here on SO!).

I'm having a similar issue trying to model siblings right now. Did you ever come up with a more satisfactory approach?
